# Determining if user is driving using gps

Tags: android, gps

Is there a way in Android to somehow use the GPS to determine if the user is driving (e.g. if the user is moving faster then say, 10 mph)? What would be even better is if there was an intent I could receive whenever the user is moving faster then 10 mph or under 10 mph, but I think I'm pushing my luck with that one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Moving at speed > 10mph doesn't necessarily mean the user is driving. They could be riding in the passenger's seat, or riding on a bus, train, plane, roller coaster, bicycle, streetcar, etc.

Comment: @Caleb - Really it doesn't matter if they are driving, riding a bike or whatever. I just want to be able to detect if the person is moving faster then 10 mph. The program I'm making will still be applicable regardless of HOW they are moving that fast.

Comment: Why answer his questions... he keeps asking them, but hasn't bothered to accept an answer since July 22.

Comment: @icemanid - You berate Caleb for focusing on the car, but that's your subject... and not updated after your little rant.

Comment: @Earl - No where in my question does the word "car" appear. I DID say "driving", however immediately afterward, I put in parenthesis my definition of driving as it relates to my question ("if the user is moving faster then say, 10 mph")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to set up some AsyncTask (background thread) with a call back function of your preference, which will be called when the speed is over 10 MPH. You can use the [Location.GetSpeed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) function.

Also, you might want to take note of the fact that it returns in meters/second. But this is a trivial conversion.

Comment: I am attempting to implement this into a background service. Will it drain the battery if I continuously poll the speed? If so, how do I get around that?

Comment: Having a background thread which would keep calling the GetSpeed() function will drain the battery somewhat. What I would do, after calling GetSpeed(), is call wait() on the thread for X amount of seconds proportional to how (targetSpeed - currentSpeed) with the assumption that it would take time to change speed. There very well might be a better way to do this.