# Find users parked car's location Android

Tags: android, gps, location, activity-recognition

how can I correctly identify if the user is driving or not ? I am trying to make an app where I can find my parked car's location.

The simplest way was to ask user to press a button after parking the car so that my app can remember its location.

But I want my app to be automatic. It should correctly recognize if the user is in vehicle or not without interacting with the user.

I tried out Activity Recognition as well but it does not give me exact/correct result. Even when I am walking it says driving and vice versa. I cannot trust it.

There are several apps in the play store which achieve this. I want to learn this as well.

Would some one take some time and help me out on this. It will be of greate help. Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: i'd say, where the speed decreases drastically (to walking speed or lower) and stays like that for a while, the person probably parked the car

Comment: is your app in the market already?

Answer (score 4):

I've never done this before, but here are some things I'd try:

- location - mainly, how fast their location is changing.  probably not great for slow traffic, but if they are moving 60mph, there's no way they are walking.  You could also combine this with map data about known roads, or maybe even use locations of well-known airports to know that someone is more likely flying than driving
- use the device's accelerometers to compute it's speed (in conjunction with location info to correct for accumulated error).
- have the user connect their device to the car with bluetooth - and then when the connection drops, you know they aren't in their car.  Or better yet, figure out if you can just detect they are in the car from strength of the bluetooth signal.  Though I'm not sure that's possible.
- (maybe) ask your users to use a simple RFID chip in their car, and then use that as an indicator of whether or not the phone is in the car.  Of course this has implications on the user experience.
- in a different vein, maybe some sensor on the device could pick up vibrations?  Just thinking that car rides aren't perfectly smooth, so any vibration sensing + some signal processing (DFT the data, then look for certain low frequencies that correspond to driving - probably low frequency and below audible).

The best?  Probably a combination of all of the above.  The more signals you can gather, the better.  Perhaps you could even collect a bunch of data, and try to use it to train a classifier?  Then again, if any one of these signals turns out to be strong enough, you might not need the others.  Be sure to test a variety of scenarios, e.g. phone in the cup holder v. in your pocket, city driving & slow traffic v. highway driving / empty streets, etc.

I'd be curious to know if any of these ideas pan out.

Also fwiw, [Determining if user is driving using gps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990926/determining-if-user-is-driving-using-gps) appears relevant - though it's a simple speed-based check - if you cruise around a parking lot at 8mph looking for a spot, you'll completely fail at catching where the car is parked if your threshold is 10mph.

Answer (score 1):

If the speed drops from above 40km/h to under 7km/h, and stays low for more than 5 minutes.